# Groupwise summary statistics for all dependent variables in R using dplyr

Tags: r

I am trying to generate groupwise (hearing - my independent variable, so HL and NH are the two groups) summary statistics (mean, sd, min, max, standard error etc. ) for each of the 10 dependent variables. I was able to do this for one variable (R_PTA) using these 2 codes:

1.

```
RightPTA <- mydata %>% group_by(NHL) %>% summarise(n=length(R_PTA), mean_R_PTA=mean(R_PTA), sd_R_PTA=sd(R_PTA), se_R_PTA=sd(R_PTA)/sqrt(length(R_PTA)), min_R_PTA=min(R_PTA), max_R_PTA=max(R_PTA))
```

2.

```
mydata
mean<-tapply(mydata$R_PTA, mydata$NHL, mean)
mean
sd<-tapply(mydata$R_PTA, mydata$NHL, sd)
sd
median<-tapply(mydata$R_PTA, mydata$NHL, median)
median
max<-tapply(mydata$R_PTA, mydata$NHL, max)
max
min<-tapply(mydata$R_PTA, mydata$NHL, min)
min
cbind(mean, sd, median, max, min)
round(cbind(mean, sd, median, max, min), digits = 1)
t1<-round(cbind(mean, sd, median, max, min), digits = 1)
t1
```

Here is the output:

```
RightearPTA
   mean  sd median  max min
HL 26.9 7.3   27.5 37.5 8.8
NH 11.6 4.1   12.5 16.2 2.5
```

I want the same exact thing for all the remaining 9 variables (L_PTA, B_PTA etc.) but in one shot if possible. Is there no way to do this? Do I have to code for each single dependent variable? I am sure its out there, but I cant find it! Any hep would be appreciated!!

Comment: I recommend making a reproducible example, but the general idea is that I recommend you use `group_by_()` and `summarize_()` so that you have flexibility with that the variable name is. Perhaps someone else would have a better approach.

Comment: @Clarinetist, the `verb_` forms are being fazed out. Agreed on the reproducible example, remember that we don't have your data!

Comment: @Axeman WOW, that's news to me! I'll have to look into this, thanks!

Comment: @Clarinetist, We can talk in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public).

Comment: @Clarinetist- Thanks for you input. If it helps here is the raw data:

Comment: NHL R_PTA L_PTA B_PTA R_SRT R_WRS L_SRT L_WRS
HL 31.28 44.27 44.56 75.24 31.28 31.28 31.28
HL 70.85 85.9 45.89 25.45 70.85 68.23 70.85
HL 44.56 12.14 44.56 44.56 44.56 17.45 44.56
HL 19.25 15.42 14.25 44.56 44.25 14.93 10.25
NH 16.28 10 44.56 14.55 68.33 44.56 10
NH 11.25 87.23 11.25 11.25 11.25 11.25 11.25
NH 89.28 89.28 13.25 89.28 89.28 89.28 89.28
NH 11.28 3.85 5.45 11.28 11.28 11.28 11.28

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46838525/edit) the question instead. Maybe you're looking for `summarise_each`. Or just use `summary` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a base R solution with `by` (the object-oriented wrapper to `tapply` to subset dataframe into factor groups) and nested `sapply` (to build matrix of stats). Below demonstrates with random, seeded data for 10 stats columns:

```
set.seed(88)

df <- data.frame(
  GROUP = sapply(seq(50), function(i) sample(c("NH", "HL"), 1, replace=TRUE)),
  STAT1 = rnorm(50)*100,
  STAT2 = rnorm(50),
  STAT3 = runif(50)*100,
  STAT4 = runif(50),
  STAT5 = rgamma(50, shape = 2)*100,
  STAT6 = rgamma(50, shape = 2),
  STAT7 = rpois(50, lambda = 100)*100,
  STAT8 = rpois(50, lambda = 100),
  STAT9 = rexp(50, rate = 1)*100,
  STAT10 = rexp(50, rate = 1)
)

dfList <- by(df, df$GROUP, FUN = function(d)
                sapply(d[2:ncol(d)], function(i) 
                  c(mean = mean(i, na.rm=TRUE),
                    sd = sd(i, na.rm=TRUE),
                    median = median(i, na.rm=TRUE),
                    min = min(i, na.rm=TRUE),
                    max = max(i, na.rm=TRUE)
                  )
                )
            )
```

Output

```
dfList$HL

#              STAT1       STAT2     STAT3      STAT4     STAT5     STAT6      STAT7     STAT8      STAT9      STAT10
# mean     -6.594221 -0.04059519 52.990723 0.58753311 157.55220 1.9196911 10103.4483 101.17241 113.089148 0.771495372
# sd      102.512709  0.99159105 31.055376 0.27339871 152.37034 1.4880694   709.3673  10.02165 121.360898 0.720117072
# median    8.034055  0.01163562 56.416484 0.56894472 136.58274 1.5150241 10200.0000 103.00000  77.302150 0.599291434
# min    -199.786535 -1.84703449  1.345751 0.00207128  22.56936 0.1553518  8400.0000  82.00000   2.396641 0.006532798
# max     251.976970  2.55701655 98.612123 0.99413520 806.38484 7.1030277 11900.0000 120.00000 487.719745 3.133768953

dfList$NH

#             STAT1       STAT2      STAT3      STAT4    STAT5    STAT6      STAT7     STAT8      STAT9    STAT10
# mean     26.51853 -0.13748799 44.1973692 0.46621478 155.7555 1.880407  9961.9048 104.38095 150.596480 1.1243476
# sd       90.57645  0.77843518 29.9227560 0.30340507 121.5361 1.105004   868.6059   8.44083 131.123059 1.1627959
# median   24.52202 -0.02949522 46.1950960 0.33646282 114.7845 1.736198  9700.0000 105.00000 122.841835 0.7819896
# min    -105.54741 -1.58980314  0.2636007 0.02044767  17.3282 0.291350  8900.0000  89.00000   7.799051 0.1108107
# max     194.78958  1.35889041 96.0175463 0.99160167 434.5724 4.368176 12000.0000 120.00000 554.307036 5.1537741
```